# Windows command wmic give Access is denied

Tags: wmic

A Windows server 2008 R2 with the name "delta" use Workgroup "WORKGROUP" (So is not a member of a domain).
On system "delta", beside account "administrator", another account "sysadmin" is created with account type Administrator.
The other Windows system has the name "gamma".
It is possible to access the system "delta" from system "gamma" with remote desktop.
This access succeeds both with the accounts "administrator" and "sysadmin" and the corresponding passwords.
From system "gamma", with the command, "wmic" data can be requested from system "delta".
This works correctly with account "administrator".

```
C:>wmic
wmic:root\cli>/node:delta /user:administrator /password:xxxxx cpu get name
Name
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1220 V2 @ 3.10GHz
```

For account "sysadmin" the command "Dcomcnfg" is started on system "delta".
Expand Component Service – Computers – My computer
Open the properties of My Computer and select “COM Security” tab.
Under COM Security, click "Edit Limits" for "Access Permissions".
The account "sysadmin" got "Remote Access".
Click "Edit Limits" for "Launch and Activation Permissions".
The account "sysadmin" got "Remote Launch" and "Remote Activation" permissions.

Expand Component Service – Computers – My computer - CDOM Config
Open the properties of "Windows Management and Instrumentation".
Choice tab "Security"
Click "Edit" for "Launch and Activation Permissions".
The account "sysadmin" got "remote Launch" and "Remote Activation" permissions.
Click "Edit" for "Access Permissions".
The account "sysadmin" got "Remote Access" permissions.

Still, I get "Access is denied" with wmic from system "gamma" to system "delta".

```
C:>wmic
wmic:root\cli>/node:delta /user:sysadmin /password:yyyyy cpu get name
Node - delta
```

> ERROR: Description = Access is denied

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Is it possible to get wmi data from a Windows systems in an other domain?
In wmic the switch "/domain" is invalid.
The use of "/user:sysadmin@omega.local" is also invalid.
Is it possible to gave the domain as parameters in wmic?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by adding permission to account "sysadmin" on system "delta" with the tools "dcomcnfg" and "wmimgmt.msc".

DCOM permission

1. Open Dcomcnfg
2. Expand Component Service -> Computers -> My computer
3. Go to the properties of My Computer
4. Select the COM Security Tab
5. Click on "Edit Limits" under Access Permissions.
6. Click "Add" and add user "sysadmin".
7. Give user "sysadmin" the "Local Access" and "Remote Access" permission.
8. Click on the "Edit Limit" for the launch and activation permissions,
9. Click "Add" and add user "sysadmin".
10. Give user "sysadmin" the "Remote Launch" and "Remote Activation"
     permission.
11. Open WMImgmt.msc
12. Go to the Properties of WMI Control
13. Go to the Security Tab
14. Select "Root" "CIMV2" and open "Security"
15. Add user "sysadmin"
16. Ensure "sysadmin" has "Execute Methods",
    "Provider Write" and "Enable Account" right;
    ensure Administrators has all permission.